# Notifying condtion_variable without unlocking mutex still works well. Why?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
 
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;
std::string data;
bool ready = false;
bool processed = false;
 
void worker_thread()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    cv.wait(lk, []{return ready;});
 
    std::cout << "Worker thread is processing data\n";
    data += " after processing";
 
    processed = true;
    std::cout << "Worker thread signals data processing completed\n";
 
    //lk.unlock(); /// here!!!!!!!!!!!
    cv.notify_one();
}
 
int main()
{
    std::thread worker(worker_thread);
 
    data = "Example data";
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m);
        ready = true;
        std::cout << "main() signals data ready for processing\n";
    }
    cv.notify_one();
 
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
        cv.wait(lk, []{return processed;});
    }
    std::cout << "Back in main(), data = " << data << '\n';
 
    worker.join();
}
```

I don't know why this code works without unlock before notify_one in worker_thread.
I think if i don't unlock before notify, Waked up main thread will block again because mutex is still held by worker_thread.
After that worker_thread will unlock mutex(because unique_lock unlock mutex when destroyed).
Then No one can wake up sleeping main thread.

But this code works well without unlocking mutex before notify.
How this works????
(I read cppreference comments, but i couldn't understand it)

Comment: The condition variable cannot stop waiting until the mutex is released, since exiting the wait required re-acquire of the mutex. Notifying after the unlock is more efficient, but not necessary. Notifying before you unlock will subject the notification to normal mutex acquire/blocking timing.

Comment: When the main thread gets woken its no longer waiting on the CV - its now waiting on the mutex. When the mutex is unlocked the main thread wakes up as this is now just the normal scenario with mutexess which dont need a wake signal.

Comment: @JohnFilleau yes in theory, but in practice OSes are optimized for that, and there is no degradation.

Comment: @sergey that's good news!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to talk about here.  First, why it works, and second, why you don't want to call unlock first.

It works because `cv.wait(lk, []{return processed;});` actually unlocks `lk` while waiting for a notification.

Some sequences.  Main gets lock first:

```
 MAIN                       WORKER
 auto lk = lock();          
                            auto lk = lock(); (blocks)
 cv.wait(lk, condition);
 checks condition; fails
 releases lk
                            wakes up with lk
                            fullfill condition
                            cv.notify_one();
 wakes up from notify
 tries to reget lk, blocks
                            lk.unlock();
 wakes up with lk.
 checks condition; passes
```

Worker gets lock first:

```
 MAIN                       WORKER
                            auto lk = lock();
 auto lk = lock(); (blocks)         
                            fullfill condition
                            cv.notify_one();
                            lk.unlock();
 wakes up with lk.
 cv.wait(lk, condition);
 checks condition; passes
```

for the case where we unlock first:

```
 MAIN                       WORKER
 auto lk = lock();          
                            auto lk = lock(); (blocks)
 cv.wait(lk, condition);
 checks condition; fails
 releases lk
                            wakes up with lk
                            fullfill condition
                            lk.unlock();
                            cv.notify_one();
 wakes up from notify
 gets lk
 checks condition; passes
```

Worker gets lock first, two possibilities at the end:

```
 MAIN                       WORKER
                            auto lk = lock();
 auto lk = lock(); (blocks)         
                            fullfill condition
                            lk.unlock();
 wakes up with lk.
 cv.wait(lk, condition);
 checks condition; passes
                            cv.notify_one(); (nobody cares)

 MAIN                       WORKER
                            auto lk = lock();
 auto lk = lock(); (blocks)         
                            fullfill condition
                            lk.unlock();
                            cv.notify_one(); (nobody cares)
 wakes up with lk.
 cv.wait(lk, condition);
 checks condition; passes
```

Now, why is it better to hold the lock?

Because the writers of C++ standard libraries made it better.  The library knows that the cv waiter is associated with a mutex, and knows this thread currently holds it.

So what actually happens is:

```
 MAIN                       WORKER
 auto lk = lock();          
                            auto lk = lock(); (blocks)
 cv.wait(lk, condition);
 checks condition; fails
 releases lk
                            wakes up with lk
                            fullfill condition
                            cv.notify_one(); // knows listener holds mutex, waits for
                            lk.unlock(); // and actually wakes up listening threads
 wakes up from notify
 gets lk
 checks condition; passes
```

Now there are far more possibilities than the above.  `condition_variable` has "spurious" wakeups, where you are woken up even though nobody notified you.  So discipline has to be followed in using it.

The general rule is that both sides must share a mutex, and the lock must be held **at any point between** the test condition changed and the notification.  And optimally, the lock should be held until immediately after the notification is sent.

This in addition to preventing race conditions on the condition state itself.  But if you use an atomic condition state, it avoids race conditions on the state, but it doesn't satisfy the locking requirements of condition variable.

The above rule -- hold the lock sometime in that interval (possibly for the entire interval) -- is a simplification, but is sufficient to guarantee you don't lose notifications.  The full rule means going back to the memory model of C++ and doing painful proofs about what your code does, and I honestly don't want to do that again.  So I use that rule of thumb.

To illustrate what can go wrong with an atomic condition "state" and no lock;

```
 MAIN                       WORKER
 auto lk = lock();
 cv.wait(lk, condition);
 checks condition; fails
                            fullfill condition
                            cv.notify_one(); (nobody cares)
 goes to sleep, releases lk
```

and nothing ever happens again.

Comment: Ok. I understand why unlock mutex before notify like this : when a thread notify cv, waiting thread wake up. but waked up thread will be trying reacquire lock but it will be blocked because notifying thread still hold lock(waked up thread by notifying should reacquire lock before checking predicate, so waked up thread can't check predicate now). after that notifying thread will release lock because unique_lock release lock when destroyed. now waked up thread is unblocked and check predicate. You're saying "spurious wakeup" indicate "waked up thread is blocked again because notifying thread

Comment: @SungJinKang I don't understand your explanation, sorry.  Spurious wakeups -- wakeups without a notification -- just happen, they are part of condition variable contract.  They may or may not occur while someone else holds a lock; if someone else holds a lock, they block on that.  If not, they gain the lock, check the condition, and otherwise act just as if someone had notified.

Comment: I'm sorry. What i say is "Hurry up and Wait" problem. Is my understanding right?? "Waked up thread is blocked again because notifying thread didn't release lock yet. After notifying thread release lock, Waked up thread can check predicate"

Comment: @SungJinKang Yes, in theory a notify could in turn block on the mutex, or a mutex unlock could then miss the signal.  In practice, according to standard library implementors who told me I was doing it wrong, the right order is signal then unlock.